# How to see Solr explain for a document not returned by Solr query

Tags: solr, lucene, explain

I am using Solr's explain to debug my Solr query.  I can see explain results for everything that Solr query returns, but not for the documents the query has not returned.

There are documents which I think should be returned by a query but are not.
I want to see how the Solr score is calculated for those documents to be able to compare with other documents.

Comment: you can check the same on the analysis page where the terms are matching for those fields...go to solr admin page ...select the core/collection and click on the analysis page...select the field and check the index and query

Comment: The analysis page shows how the fields are processed during indexing and querying, not the results of explain and how the final score is calculated.

Comment: Just add the "debug=true" parameter to your query and you'll be able to see the whole explain

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti It seems like you haven't read the question carefully. I am already using explain.

Comment: explain you will explain about the score of matching documents only...and not the not matching documents

Comment: The `score` does not decide if a document is being returned or not. The only thing that affects whether a document gets returned is the filters that are being applied, either through the query `q` or through the filter queries `fq`. You can debug those through the analysis page as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the answer to this question.
There's a query parameter called explainOther. You can specify a query in this parameter and on top of the explain you will get for the matched queries, now Solr will show you the explain for any record that matches this new explainOther query as well.

Here is the explanation of that parameter from Solr reference guide:

#### The explainOther Parameter

(From: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/common-query-parameters.html#CommonQueryParameters-TheexplainOtherParameter)

The explainOther parameter specifies a Lucene query in order to identify a set of documents. If this parameter is included and is set to a non-blank value, the query will return debugging information, along with the "explain info" of each document that matches the Lucene query, relative to the main query (which is specified by the q parameter). For example:

q=supervillians&debugQuery=on&explainOther=id:juggernaut
The query above allows you to examine the scoring explain info of the top matching documents, compare it to the explain info for documents matching id:juggernaut, and determine why the rankings are not as you expect.

The default value of this parameter is blank, which causes no extra "explain info" to be returned.